# Suppose $n\in\mathbb{N}.$ Partition $\{1,2,3,\ldots,2n\}$ into $n$ pairs. Is it true that the maximum pair product is $\geq n^2 ?\ $ Or $\geq n(n+1)?$

Tags: examples-counterexamples, pigeonhole-principle

Suppose $n\in\mathbb{N}.$ Partition $S_n:=\{1,2,3,\ldots,2n\}$ into $n$ pairs. Is it true that the maximum pair product is $\geq n^2 ?\ $ Or $\geq n(n+1)?$

So for example for $n=3$, we have: $S_3:=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}.$  If we partition it like this: $(1,6), (2,5),\ (3,4),\ $ the largest pair product is $3\times 4 = 12 > 9.$ We can easily check by brute force that however we partition $S_3$ into three pairs, the maximum of all pair products will be $>3^2 =9.$ In fact it will be $\geq 3\times 4 = 12.$

If we try to look for a counter-example to the conjecture, we write pairs starting with the largest number in the first entry, then the second number is the greatest number such that that pair product is $<n^2$ and continue down, then for example, for $n=15,$ ($15^2 = 225)$, we get: $(30, 7),\ (29, 6),\ (28, 8),\ (27, 5),\ (26, 4),\ (25, 3),\ (24, 9),\ (23, 2),\ (22, 10),\ (21, 1),\ (20, 11),\ $ but now we have to do $(19,12)$ and $19\times 12 > 225.$

I suspect the propositions are probably true, but I don't see how to actually prove it.

Comment: Any pair $(a,b)$ will have the smaller member and the larger member of the pair.  By the pigeonhole principle we must have at least one pair where the smaller member is greater than or equal to $n.$

Comment: @user317176 I did not think of that! I think that constitutes an answer. I think this is a case where the answer is so simple, but I did not think about the pigeonhole principle in the right way to tackle the problem. So I think it is useful and will not delete the question.